# JSSOR $ScaleWidth() not working on Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, responsive, jssor

I have been working to put 2 JSSOR sliders on a webpage and overall have been having alot of luck except for I've found that the responsive code I've added to the page works on my desktop, but when I test on my Android, the slider doesn't resize.  The div is so I can output the value of the resize, and I confirmed that that # is being passed properly at least.  Here is the script for one of the sliders, again working on desktop, not on android...(ps on the phone I get a minSliderWidth value of 360px..on my desktop I can resize smaller then that)

```
<div id="value"></div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/_scripts/jssor.slider.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
        init_jssor_slider1 = function (containerId) {

        var options = {
            $Loop: 1,
            $DragOrientation: 1,
            $SlideDuration: 500,
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: { 
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
                $ChanceToShow: 2,
                $AutoCenter: 2,
                $Steps: 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        //Responsive code
        function ScaleSlider() {

            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;

            if (parentWidth) {
                minSliderWidth = Math.min(parentWidth, 482)

                document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = minSliderWidth;

                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(minSliderWidth);
            }else{
                document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = Here;

                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30)
            }


        };

        ScaleSlider();
        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider)

    };
</script>
```

The relavant CSS is:

```
#slider1_container {
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 482px;
height: 626px;
overflow: hidden;}

#slider2_container {
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
float: right;
width: 482px;
height: 626px;
overflow: hidden;}
```

I've tried everything and I can not see why this wouldn't work on mobile as I've followed everything I can find to no avail.  Whats ironic is as I was originally building the slider it was resizing on its own without using the $ScaleWidth(), via CSS I guess, but I can't remember how I had it setup :-)

Comment: URL where you see -> http://www.mandysaile.com/indextest.html  I only have one JSSOR slider on it right now as I am trouble shooting.

Comment: Is it possible to access the  <div data-u="slides" via css?  I could just sent width and height in css for regular, and use a media query to set it for narrow (mobile).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set css rule with class name instead of id.

```
.slider1_container {
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 482px;
height: 626px;
overflow: hidden;}

.slider2_container {
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
float: right;
width: 482px;
height: 626px;
overflow: hidden;}
```

Also, if you put the `slider1_container` inside of another div, please set `overflow:hidden;` for the div.

Comment: If I change the ID to a class, the whole slider breaks?  this is the top structure right now:  <div class="slider1_container">
    <div data-u="slides" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 482px; height: 626px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div><img data-u="image" src="home/_images/Home_SmallSliderLeft_01.jpg" />

Comment: See `<div id="slider1_container" class="slider1_container">`

Comment: I added that line to my html and changed the element reference in my css to .slider1_container {   ...  but it did nothing.  The slider works on a computer properly, but doesn't resize on mobile still.  I've asked some friends to test on their smaller tablets and phones and they get the same thing.  No resizing? :-(  Is there a way to reference the data-u element in my css perhaps?  I might just put in a media statement and shink the slider that way for small devices.

Comment: Media statement css will not make the slider responsive.

Comment: As the slider will resize to width of its container, please make sure the container is responsive. Also, please try to add `overflow:hidden;` for the container.